# How do you stop the screen from dimming in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, brightness, screen-brightness

I'm creating a simple flash light app. Whenever I turn the screen all white, the screen dims a little, even if I turn off auto brightness and set the brightness to high.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can disable this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a "feature" of all Samsung Focuses b/c of their AMOLED screen.  The screen automatically dims itself and there's no API to disable this behavior.

Bummer

Answer (score 3):

You should look at disabling the [UserIdleDetectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to prevent this.

Please be sure to read the remarks on the MSDN article though regarding battery life.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make a difference.  The UserIdleDetectionMode doesn't kick off until after a few minutes anyways.  This dimming is instantaneous.  Turn out this is something built into all Samusung Focus phones and can't be disabled